Typescript to C# Timespan
I have this object in my C# BackEnd which uses timespan
 public class TurnoDTONew : LiveCareBaseDTO
 {
     //public int ID_OPERATORE { get; set; }
     public DayOfWeek GiornoDellaSettimana { get; set; }
     public TimeSpan Dalle { get; set; }
     public TimeSpan Alle { get; set; }

     public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
         List<ValidationResult> Result = new List<ValidationResult>();
        // if (ID_OPERATORE == 0) Result.Add(new ValidationResult("Il campo ID_Utente non può essere 0"));

         return Result;
     }
 }

I made the same object in my front end so i can use it to call the server method, but i'm getting bad request error, probably because i'm using typescript "time" type which is not the same as timespan.
Front-end Turni object:
export interface TurniDTONew {
    GiornoSettimana: DayEnum,
    Dalle: Time,
    Alle: Time
}

Front-end function calling the backend method:
public PutTurnoNew(ID: number, Turno: TurniDTONew[]): Promise<OperatoreDTOTurno>{
        return new Promise (async (resolve,reject) =>{
            const strUrl: string = this.m_objEnvironmentService.GlobalVariables.ApiUrl + 'Operatore/' + ID + '/Turni'
            this.m_objHttpClient.put<OperatoreDTOTurno>(strUrl, Turno).subscribe(
                {
                    next: objTurno =>{
                        resolve(objTurno);
                    },
                    error: async objError =>{
                        reject('PutTurnoNew ->' +objError)
                    }
                }
            )
        })
    }

Backend function (just for info)
[HttpPut("{IDOperatore}/Turni")]
[Authorize(Policy = "Turni-Update")]
public ActionResult<OperatoreDTOTurno?> PutOperatoreTurni(int IDOperatore, [FromBody] List<TurnoDTONew> Request)
{
    LiveCareContext? objDb;
    try
    {
        objDb = LiveCareMainDBContex.GetCurrentContext(User.Claims.ToList());
        if (objDb != null)
        {
            OperatoreEF? objOperatoreEF = objDb.Operatori?.Where(Operatore => Operatore.ID == IDOperatore).Include(Operatore => Operatore.Turni) .FirstOrDefault();
            if (objOperatoreEF != null )//&& objOperatoreEF.Turni != null)
            {
                objDb.BeginTRansaction();
                try
                {
                    
                    if (objOperatoreEF.Turni != null)
                    {                            
                    foreach (var item in objOperatoreEF.Turni)
                    {
                        objDb?.Turni?.Remove(item);
                    }
                    objOperatoreEF.Turni.Clear();
                    foreach (TurnoDTONew objTurno in Request)
                    {
                        TurnoEF objTurnoEF = m_objMapper.Map<TurnoEF>(objTurno);
                        objTurnoEF.ID_OPERATORE = IDOperatore;
                        objDb?.Turni?.Add(objTurnoEF);
                        objOperatoreEF?.Turni?.Add(objTurnoEF);
                    }
                    objDb?.SaveChanges();
                    objDb?.CommitTransaction();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objDb?.RollBackTransaction();
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception Ex)
                {
                    objDb?.RollBackTransaction();
                    return BadRequest(Ex.ToString());
                }
                OperatoreDTOTurno objOperatoreDTO = m_objMapper.Map<OperatoreDTOTurno>(objOperatoreEF);
                return Ok(objOperatoreDTO);
            }
            else
                return NotFound();
        }
        return BadRequest("Impossibile Connettersi al DataBase");
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        m_logger.LogWarning(Ex.ToString());
        return BadRequest(Ex.ToString());    
    }
}


What is the best thing to do to use timestamp in typescript? I also tried using a timestamp class found here:  https://gist.github.com/ranwahle/e78a8859ff78bdd68055017fc5875fcb, but i have no idea on how to initialize that

Well personally I found it easier if you convert the DateTime into a string and send it to the frontend. Unless you need to do anything with the DateTime than displaying
